# Usage of complex filters in communication

Tags: digital-communications, digital-filter

In the last stage of a communication transmitter, at the front end a filter is used to eliminate unwanted signals from other frequencies. As far as I read in literature, are these filters "real" filters? Why can't we use a complex filter in communications?

If the answer is no, can you give me an application where complex filters are used ? (In signal processing).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any electromagnetic signal is real-valued, and hardware filters thus have real inputs and outputs, so their transfer function must be real-valued as well.

In principle it would be possible to build a complex-valued hardware filter, by creating two filters and using one of the outputs as I and the other as Q signal, however this is useful only with a complex input, requiring you to build four filters (I->I, I->Q, Q->I, Q->Q), one adder (for the Q outputs) and one subtractor (for the I outputs), which is difficult to do in hardware.

Thus, you can see complex-valued filters in digital signal processing mostly.

Complex filters are useful if you need an asymmetric frequency response.

In digital communication, many transceivers are built using the [direct conversion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-conversion_receiver) paradigm for cost reasons, which leaves the (complex-valued) signal centered around 0 Hz.

Filtering that signal does not require an asymmetric transfer function, so the complex signal is passed through a real-valued filter, using two separate filters with the same transfer function.

There are a few use cases for complex-valued filters on complex-valued signals, but these are usually few and far between, so you stumble over them seldom.

Comment: A real-valued filter generally does not have a real-valued transfer function. It only has a real-valued impulse response.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, complex filters (polyphase filters) are used in communication systems.
Thus, sufficient image rejection can be achieved with low-order filter stages.
This is importanrt, in particular, for mobile integrated comm systems.
As another feature, complex filters possess a symmetric transfer characteristic (symmetric curve for linear frequency axis).

Comment: No. complex filters are not necessarily polyphase filters or vice versa. Complex filters have an asymmetric transfer function.

Comment: Why a complex filter is named "complex"? Because it uses two signals which are shifted by 90 deg. Therefore, it belongs to the class of polyphase filters. The transfer function, indeed, is symmetrical (for a linear frequency axis).

Comment: The 90 degree shift is not a shift in time. Both real and imaginary part are processed in parallel.

Comment: A complex filter is simply a filter with a complex-valued impulse response \$h(n)\$. Polyphase filters are a specific implementation and have nothing to do with complex filters. Furthermore, complex filters generally do not show any symmetry in their frequency response. It's the other way around, for a *real-valued* filter, the frequency response satisfies \$H(\omega)=H^*(-\omega)\$.

Comment: @Matt L: Well - I think, it is not the first time that we have different definitions which are responsible for some misunderstandings. The following excerpt is taken from an introductory text (Complex Signal Processing) written from the well-known Ken Martin (Toronto Univ.) : 
"The poly-phase network is well-analyzed in [19]
where it is shown that it is an example of a complex filter obtained from frequency-shifting a high-pass filter as is discussed in section 4."

Comment: I would say that this is in agreement with my comment. A polyphase network can be *an example* of a complex filter. But your answer seems to imply that complex filters are polyphase filters and vice verse, which simply isn't correct.

Comment: Matt - my answer was nothing else than a comment to your statement that "Polyphase filters...have nothing to do with complex filters". (By the way: I never used the phrase "vice versa").